# I'd like to run Ubuntu with btrfs subvolumes and the drive must be encrypted

Tags: encryption, btrfs

I'd like to run Ubuntu on a encrypted drive. I'd also like to use btrfs subvolumes so I can use the super cool snapshot feature. The installer supports one or the other. I've tried doing an arch style install using debootstrap and I got most the way thru it but It wouldn't boot, I had some grub issues. Once I booted from the grub command line I got stuck in initramfs and never got asked for a password, maybe I didn't setup my crypttab right. I'm thinking of trying again with some more knowledge, I learned a lot despite the results. Chating with chatGTP it suggested doing the install with encryption. moving everything on root to the "@" subvolume and do the same with home to "@home". This might be easier but the I'm stuck with LVM I don't really want that. So I thought I'd ask here and maybe there is some way I'm not thinking of? Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but if it’s snapshots you’re looking for, why not use ZFS? Ubuntu has better tooling and support for that file system over Btrfs 

Comment: I like how btrfs works on my arch machine and I'd like the same functionality in ubuntu

Comment: Also as far as zfs is concerned it's the same problem that you have to pick encryption or zfs not both.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get it done is to install 22.10.  You can encrypt your partition and format it, then pick it in the installer for / and use other partitions for  /boot and /boot/efi.  Run the installer then before restarting chroot into the new install and set up a crypttap.  This guide has the steps to do the install and chroot into the drive.  You don't have to use LVM like in the guide and ignore the windows parts. https://gist.github.com/luispabon/db2c9e5f6cc73bb37812a19a40e137bc
Also then you do do-release-upgrade and your at 23.04.